# Order by desc and group by on cross table query

Tags: mysql

I've tried a few options I've seen for getting GROUP BY and ORDER BY to work together...but I can't get the right results.

```
feeding_types table
    id                          
    type                            
    quantity                                            
    feeding_id

feedings table
    id                                                      
    data_entry_id
```

The basic part of the query returns the following:

```
        id      type        feeding_id
        15236   dried_comm  13499
        15237   dried_comm  13500
        15286   dried_comm  13543
        15287   dried_comm  13544
        15294   tinned_comm 13550
        15295   dried_comm  13551
        15296   dried_comm  13552
```

What I want to do is use GROUP BY to get the latest dried_comm and tinned_comm records from these results, and filter out the rest.

I've tried this:

```
SELECT ft . * , MAX( ft.id ) ID
FROM feeding_types ft
INNER JOIN feeding_types ft2 ON ft2.id = ft.ID
JOIN feedings f1 ON ft.feeding_id = f1.id
WHERE f1.data_entry_id = 15758
GROUP BY ft.type
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

which results in:

```
id      type       feeding_id   ID 
15236   dried_comm  13499   15296
15294   tinned_comm 13550   15294
```

EDIT: the expected results would be 
    id      type       feeding_id   ID 
    15296   dried_comm  13552   15296
    15294   tinned_comm 13550   15294

Any ideas how to get this working correctly?

Comment: What values determine "the latest dried_comm and tinned_comm records"? And could you add expected results to the question?

Comment: Just the highest ID for each, I've added expected results to the question, cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The underlying logic does not match very well your actual algorithm. Let me suggest the following instead:

```
SELECT ft.*
FROM feeding_types ft
    JOIN (
        SELECT type, MAX(id) AS id 
        FROM feeding_types 
        GROUP BY type
    ) t ON t.type = ft.type AND t.id = ft.id
    JOIN feedings f1 ON ft.feeding_id = f1.id AND f1.data_entry_id = 15758
```

Comment: If the PK of `feeding_types` table is the `id` column then the join condition between `ft` and `f` could be simplified thus: `ON t.id = ft.id`.

Comment: this is correct, yet I kept it for clarity purpose as I was not sure.

Comment: @Sebas - perfect, just had to add an alias for the feeding_types subquery and it's working nicely, thanks